# Shuffling the columns of a matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms, random

Suppose I have an $N\times k$ matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1} & \cdots & a_{N,1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{1,k} & \cdots & a_{N,k} \end{bmatrix}$$

Is there a *stateless* function (or algorithm) that will shuffle the $k$ elements in each column randomly, while preserving the columns?

For example, if $N=2$ and $k=3$, we could have:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1} & a_{2,1} \\
a_{1,2} & a_{2,2} \\
a_{1,3} & a_{2,3} \end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1} & a_{2,3} \\
a_{1,3} & a_{2,1} \\
a_{1,2} & a_{2,2} \end{bmatrix}$$

---

**EDIT** By "stateless", I suppose I really mean something like "deterministic while not relying on external state". I'm thinking of this from a computer science perspective, to resolve the contradiction of "random" and "deterministic"; that is, a function that takes a seed -- i.e., for a random number generator -- as its argument. (The input matrix is always the same, so I guess it's not needed as input.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_{ij}$ be the permutation matrix that exchanges row $i$ with row $j$. Then you can exchange *column* $i$ with *column* $j$ by applying the associated permutation matrix to the **transpose** of your matrix, then transposing back:

Comment: Thank you :) That just leaves me with the need for a deterministic permutation matrix generator, but that's pretty straightforward and an implementation detail!

Comment: In my currently fatigued state, it didn't occur to me that the permutation matrix applies uniformly to rows. Thus, I suppose, to get the effect I am after, I would need to break the matrix up into $N$ (column) vectors, then apply a different permutation matrix to each, then reassemble (with the appropriate transposing inbetween)

Comment: @Xophmeister that won't shuffle columns...that will shuffle elements of the matrix. A series or row permutations in the transpose will result in shuffles columns after taking the transpose.

Comment: I'm probably being stupid (highly likely), but for example, how would the $3\times 3$ permutation matrix in my example look? I can construct matrices that permute the transposed columns together, but I can't construct one which permutes them independently (i.e., different permutations *per column*).

Comment: @Xophmeister you cant with a single matrix. You would need your column-wise approach.